# Retrieve date part from column

Tags: sql-server

A column name rcvdate, which is having datetime type, the value is like this:

```
2009-10-20 10:00:00
```

I want to do a select, my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM data 
WHERE rcvdate = '2009-10-20'
```

Not working, I am  expecting  runnable query as I checked lots of query but they did't worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check against an interval if you want all rows for one day:

```
SELECT * 
FROM data 
WHERE rcvdate >= '20091020' AND
      rcvdate < DATEADD(day, 1, '20091020')
```

From SQL Server 2008 you can use this instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM data 
WHERE CAST(rcvdate as DATE) = '2009-10-20'
```

[Cast to date is sargable but is it a good idea?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea)

Comment: The first method doesn't have a function on a column = better performance

Comment: @gbn - Cast `datetime` to date is sargable. Do you mean that it is slower anyway?

Comment: @gbn - [Yes](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/526431/make-more-functions-sargable)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE CONVERT(rcvdate, date) = '2009-10-20'
```

You should convert your datetime-field to date-field, because in your query '2009-10-20' converts to datetime '2009-10-20 00:00:00'

**UPD:**

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE CAST(rcvdate AS date) = '2009-10-20'
```

will have the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You can go below way, it works always, thanks

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE 
   DATEDIFF(dd,0,rcvdate ) 
      BETWEEN DATEDIFF(dd,0,'2009-10-20') AND
      DATEDIFF(dd,0,'2009-10-20')
```

here is the reference, you can use different ways to convert date. http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/

Thanks